# Android: Get native HardwareBuffer Format (ImageFormat.PRIVATE)

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-mediacodec

I'm trying to figure out if I can use the `HardwareBuffer.USAGE_GPU_SAMPLED_IMAGE` flag in my `ImageReader` constructor:

```kotlin
val format = ImageFormat.PRIVATE // or ImageFormat.YUV_420_888
val imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
  width,
  height,
  format,
  MAX_IMAGES,
  HardwareBuffer.USAGE_GPU_SAMPLED_IMAGE // <-- this one
)
```

To find out if that is supported, I am using the `HardwareBuffer.isSupported` method:

```kotlin
val supportsGpuFlag = HardwareBuffer.isSupported(
  width,
  height,
  ???, // <-- what do I put here?
  1,
  HardwareBuffer.USAGE_GPU_SAMPLED_IMAGE // <-- check if GPU is supported
)
```

I am usually working with `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888` images, but there are some applications where I can switch to `ImageFormat.PRIVATE` images which makes the pipeline significantly more efficient.

I guess `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888` is equivalent to `HardwareBuffer.YCBCR_420_888`, but what is `ImageFormat.PRIVATE` equivalent to?

On my emulator I tested streaming PRIVATE images and check their HardwareBuffer format which yielded `HardwareBuffer.RGB_565`, but I'm guessing this is different from device to device and is probably `HardwareBuffer.YCBCR_420_888` on most devices.

But how do I get that at runtime?

**TL;DR:** I want to get the HardwareBuffer format equivalent of `ImageFormat.PRIVATE` flag at runtime.